# QtDesigner for Android - I'm not getting what I see at all, padding has no effect

Tags: android, qt, qt-designer

I created simple Qt iu form in Qt Designer. I thought it is kind of WYSIWYG editor for Qt, but I'm starting to think it's more like [WYSITUTWYG](https://xkcd.com/1341/).

Jokes aside, I am trying to use CSS as much as possible so that we can quickly change design once we have an idea that doesn't look like crap. This is the CSS, which is applied to `MainWindow`:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
QWidget {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
}
*[class="h1"] {
    color: yellow;
    background-color: rgb(50, 191, 12); /* light green*/
    font-size: 15pt;
    padding: 6px 8px 6px 8px;
}
QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(50, 191, 12); /* light green*/
    color: black;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
*[class="datapointWidget"], DataPoint {
   border: 1px solid white;
}
```

I am using custom [dynamic property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-widget-mode.html#dynamic-properties) to use `[class="h1"]` selector. This one thing actually works really well.

[image: image description]

This is the result:

[image: image description]

As you can see we have some problems here:

- padding has no effect at all
- magically, yellow border appeared around headings
- buttons did show green background but still also render natively
- DataPoint widget has no border

One thing that actually holds well is the weird right margin - the one thing I hoped was just a Designer visual bug, but actually appears in the program.

Comment: off-topic comment: qt on android - are you masochist? yes, maybe you feel better with C++ but seriously, it shouldn't take much time to learn(or polish) java and build native android's app

Comment: @Selvin There's a huge C++ TCP protocol library I would have to re-implement in Java. Not mentioning that I spent over a half a year intensive programming in java and it sucks in every aspect possible. Btw C++ is *native* - that's where the name native development kit comes from. We can start a chat about this if you wanna talk about it.

Comment: I prefer C# but have to live with java in "android context" ... anyway does this library have some qt references? why i'm asking ... because you could wrapped it with some JNI code ... make native ui(that's what i meant using "native" in my prev comment) but use the C++ library underhood ...

Comment: @Selvin Here's the link to the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96988/java-c-android . Sorry but discussing this in comments will just confuse other people coming here - and any moderator is rightful to delete this discussion.